# not able to find button , selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button

[image]

Please find the above image to inspect.

I want to click not now button but it is not able find it.

I have tried below code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click()
notification1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'pV7Qt')]")
offbt = notification1.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='ABCxa']//*[@class='cmbtv']//*[@class='sqdOP yWX7d    "
                                            "y3zKF     ']")
offbt.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
notification = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'pbNvD')]")
offbt1 = notification.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='piCib']//*[@class='mt3GC']//*[@class='aOOlW   HoLwm ']")
offbt1.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this xpath :

```
//button[text()='Not Now']
```

and I would suggest you to have explicit wait introduce while automating insta :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but after clicking next window button is not working which was working previously _https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198324/not-now-button-not-getting-clicked-in-instagram-unable-to-locate-element_  refer this question i guess you only have answered this question.

Comment: that answer was given by `hugo alejandro guerra peralta`, I only formatted that answer. anyway, what is the error when you try to interact with `next window button`

Comment: Oops sorry my bad !